# trigger a function from shared library bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, shared-libraries

I have a shared library function that get a list of IP's and verify that our service is running on it using gradle.

```
def verifyAllInstances () {
    sh '''
        for instanceid in `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --auto-scaling-group-name my_asg --region us-east-1 | jq .AutoScalingGroups[].Instances[].InstanceId -r`; do
            echo ${instanceid} 
            instanceIP=`aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --instance-ids ${instanceid} | jq .Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress -r`
            ./gradlew  testInstance -PserverUrl=http://${instanceIP}:8080
        done
    '''
}
```

I want to create another test function to execute the gradle command

```
    def testInstance (String instanceIP)
    {
        sh "./gradlew  testInstance -PserverUrl=http://${instanceIP}:8080"
}
```

but can't trigger the second function from the first one ...
any ideas ?